# Extend each IF statement to set Null

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have the following code I am struggling with. I would like to extend each IF statement to set Null on a clonedGeneratedPegs.PegPosition depending on the outcome of the result and I have no concept on how to do this?

I have a series of pegs in positions 1 - 4. One series (clonedGeneratedPegs) is a set of randomly generated pegs (e.g. Red, Blue, Green, Green). The others are user generated clonedUserGuess (e.g. Yellow, Yellow, Blue, Blue)

The IF statements below work in so far as that if it returns true it adds white pegs to my list, however using the colour examples above the results would be in accurate as far as my task is concerned in that I should only return on white peg to the pegResultContainer. Not as it currently does (add 2) as my 3 and 4 statements would both add white pegs to my list

So using IF blocks 3 and 4 as my examples
IF: 
clonedGeneratedPegs.PegPosition.PegPositon2 was Blue and the user clonedUserGuess.PegPosition3 was Blue add to list and set the clonedGeneratedPegs.PegPosition.PegPositon2 = Null

This should mean that if clonedUserGuess.PegPosition4 was also Blue it will not be added to the pegResultContainer and I will only return 1 white peg as I have already set the clonedGeneratedPegs.PegPosition.PegPositon2 to NULL.

```
if (clonedUserGuess.PegPosition1 != null && clonedGeneratedPegs.Contains(clonedUserGuess.PegPosition1.Colour))
                pegResultContainer.ResultPegs.Add(new Peg { Colour = PegColour.White });


            if (clonedUserGuess.PegPosition2 != null && clonedGeneratedPegs.Contains(clonedUserGuess.PegPosition2.Colour))
                pegResultContainer.ResultPegs.Add(new Peg { Colour = PegColour.White });

            if (clonedUserGuess.PegPosition3 != null && clonedGeneratedPegs.Contains(clonedUserGuess.PegPosition3.Colour))
                pegResultContainer.ResultPegs.Add(new Peg { Colour = PegColour.White });

            if (clonedUserGuess.PegPosition4 != null && clonedGeneratedPegs.Contains(clonedUserGuess.PegPosition4.Colour))
                pegResultContainer.ResultPegs.Add(new Peg { Colour = PegColour.White });


            return pegResultContainer;
```

I really can’t see how to tell each IF block to set its corresponding clonedGeneratedPegs Position to NULL

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: It might help if you could try to simplify your description. At least to me, it's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: Position  datatype is int ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the biggest improvement you should make here is to use an array for the peg positions, rather than individual properties. That will allow you to use looping control structures to handle the comparison, rather than duplicating code. It will also make handling the red vs white result pegs easier.

The other change I would make is to do the check for the red result pegs first, as that is the stricter comparison.

With the above in mind, I would imagine the code would look something like this:

```
PegColour[] CheckPegs(PegColour[] userGuess, PegColour[] generated)
{
    bool[] matched = new bool[userGuess.Length];
    List<PegColour> result = new List<PegColour>();

    // Look for exact matches
    for (int i = 0; i < userGuess.Length; i++)
    {
        if (userGuess[i] == generated[i])
        {
            result.Add(PegColour.Red);
            matched[i] = true;
        }
    }

    if (result.Count != userGuess.Length)
    {
        // Look for colour matches in wrong position
        for (int i = 0; i < userGuess.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!matched[i])
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < generated.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (!matched[j] && userGuess[i] == generated[j])
                    {
                        result.Add(PegColour.White);
                        matched[j] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Note the use of a third array to keep track of which pegs have already been matched, thus taking them out of consideration for further checks. You could in fact use `null` values in one of the arrays (e.g. the `generated` array, which would match the above implementation…you could use the `userGuess` array instead, but then the loops in the "…wrong position" section above would need to be reversed), but that requires modifying the input arrays (which in turn is probably why you have "cloned" data structures?).

Using the third `bool[]` object, you can keep track of the information needed without modifying the input arrays at all.

If you do not find the above help, please edit your question so that it includes [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario, so that it is easier to understand the question and so that a better answer can be provided.